# Printing Image from Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing

I'm trying to print a Image in Landscape mode in `Silverlight`.

I found a great example [here](http://earok.net/sections/articles/web-dev/easy-landscape-printing-silverlight). Where most of the code comes from. The code worked perfectly as expected. When I changed the Line to an Image it failed.

**Code**

```
       Canvas OuterCanvas = new Canvas();


       /* a container for everything that will print */

       Border OuterBorder = new Border()
       {

           BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),

           BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),

           Margin = new Thickness(10)

       };

       double Width = e.PrintableArea.Width - OuterBorder.Margin.Left - OuterBorder.Margin.Right;

       double Height = e.PrintableArea.Height - OuterBorder.Margin.Top - OuterBorder.Margin.Bottom;


       /* NOTE: We're trying to force landscape, so swop the width and height */

       OuterBorder.Width = Height;

       OuterBorder.Height = Width;


       /* on portrait, this line goes down (leave the printer settings, we're trying to force landscape) */

       Line Line = new Line()
       {

           X1 = OuterBorder.Width / 2,

           Y1 = 0,

           X2 = OuterBorder.Width / 2,

           Y2 = OuterBorder.Height,

           Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),

           StrokeThickness = 3

       };


       //
       // Here is where I changed the Line to an Image
       //
       OuterBorder.Child = imageElementInXaml; //Line;

       OuterCanvas.Children.Add(OuterBorder);


       /* rotate 90 degrees, and move into place */

       var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();

       transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform() { Angle = 90 });

       transformGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform() { X = e.PrintableArea.Width });

       OuterBorder.RenderTransform = transformGroup;

       e.PageVisual = OuterCanvas;

       e.HasMorePages = false;
```

I know that a `Border` can only contain 1 element in which I have done so, and when I printed the image on its own without trying to make it landscape this worked too. So why wont it work when I simply replace the `Line` with the image `Element`

Comment: Could it be that you are invoking this code before the image in XAML has a chance to load?

Comment: No because the image had loaded and the code above is in a button click event handler

Comment: Did you try instantiating and adding a new Image from scratch, instead of using the one in your XAML?

Comment: Yup.. I did, Ive since updated my code from another source I found which seems to work fine.

Comment: So, for future reference to visitors of this question, what is the final solution? By the way you can post it as an answer to your own question and mark it as answered, that's perfectly valid.

Comment: Ill post it, but wont mark it as correct because its not really solving the problem I have above. cheers

Answer (score 0):

So since posting this I found some code (cant remember where now) that has helped me get the printing working. Its not as clean as I would have liked but it works.

```
    void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        Image image = new Image();

        image.Source = imgPlayer.Source;


        //This is important
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;


        // Find the full size of the page
        Size pageSize =  new Size(e.PrintableArea.Width  + e.PageMargins.Left + e.PageMargins.Right, e.PrintableArea.Height + e.PageMargins.Top + e.PageMargins.Bottom);

        var MARGIN= 10;

        // Get additional margins to bring the total to MARGIN (= 96)
        Thickness additionalMargin = new Thickness
        {
            Left = Math.Max(0, MARGIN - e.PageMargins.Left),
            Top = Math.Max(0, MARGIN - e.PageMargins.Top),
            Right = Math.Max(0, MARGIN - e.PageMargins.Right),
            Bottom = Math.Max(0, MARGIN - e.PageMargins.Bottom)
        };


        // Find the area for display purposes
        Size displayArea = new Size(e.PrintableArea.Width - additionalMargin.Left - additionalMargin.Right,  e.PrintableArea.Height  - additionalMargin.Top - additionalMargin.Bottom);

        bool pageIsLandscape = displayArea.Width > displayArea.Height;
        bool imageIsLandscape = image.ActualWidth > image.ActualHeight;

        double displayAspectRatio = displayArea.Width / displayArea.Height;
        double imageAspectRatio = (double)image.ActualWidth / image.ActualHeight;

        double scaleX = Math.Min(1, imageAspectRatio / displayAspectRatio);
        double scaleY = Math.Min(1, displayAspectRatio / imageAspectRatio);



        // Calculate the transform matrix
        MatrixTransform transform = new MatrixTransform();

        if (pageIsLandscape == imageIsLandscape)
        {
        // Pure scaling
            transform.Matrix = new Matrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {

            // Scaling with rotation
            scaleX *= pageIsLandscape ? displayAspectRatio : 1 /   displayAspectRatio;
            scaleY *= pageIsLandscape ? displayAspectRatio : 1 /   displayAspectRatio;

            transform.Matrix = new Matrix(0, scaleX, -scaleY, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        Image image2 = new Image
        {
            Source = image.Source,
            Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
            Width = displayArea.Width,
            Height = displayArea.Height,
            RenderTransform = transform,
            RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Margin = additionalMargin,
        };

        Border border = new Border
        {
            Child = image,
        };

        e.PageVisual = border;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, should the last part be `Border border= new Border { Child=image2};` instead? Otherwise I cannot see any reason to create image2 ?

Comment: Yes I think you're right, but then in that case I havnt tested it with `Border border= new Border { Child=image2};` :)

Comment: Because if the code as it stands is correct, and deleting the code block instantiating image2 stops the function from working, then there is something very different going on behind the scenes here.